# Passing parameter in Update-FederatedHybridSearchForM365.ps1 script for hybrid search with SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, hybrid-search

There is a notification from Microsoft about the Hybrid search update which says if we use hybrid search we must execute the Update-FederatedHybridSearchForM365.ps1 script before October 1st, 2021 otherwise your hybrid will stop working. The script can be downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/103240).

Script execution parameter format:

```
Update-FederatedHybridSearchForM365.ps1 -HybridWebApp [YourHybridWebApplication] [-Force]
```

**Description about the -HybridWebApp parameter**

The internal URL of your on-premises primary web application, such as http://sharepoint or https://sharepoint.adventureworks.com.
This value is a full URL using the proper protocol (either http: // or https:// ).
This is the internal URL of the web application that you are using for hybrid functionality.
An example is http://sharepoint or https://sharepoint.adventureworks.com.

**My question is** - in our SharePoint on-premise environment, inside the cloud search content source we have configured five web applications for the hybrid search functionality, then out of these five web applications, how to justify which is the primary web application or should we execute this script for all the five web applications?

Anyone could please share your experience with this if you have already executed or know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you should execute the script for only one web application to register new Service Principal for Federated Search Skill in SharePoint Online, register new Application Principal for Federated Search Skill in SharePoint On-Premises, register EVO/eSTS as a Trusted Token Issuer at SharePoint On-Premises and grant appropriate permissions to SharePoint On-Premises Federated Search Skill Application Principal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Emily Du - MSFT . Could you please confirm whether we should execute this only for one web application, I am a little scared to make the decision until we get the confirmation?

Comment: In my opinion, register new principals and grant permission is a one-time operation.

If you want to get a certain confirmation, I suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft to confirm.

Comment: I raised a ticket to Microsoft from Office 365 admin center page, but they said, as this script should be executed in SharePoint on-premise server, so this is out of the scope from their end. Apparently, they guided me to raise a ticket to Microsoft for on-premise server support, but that is paid service - we don't want to opt for paid service.

Comment: I have got confirmation from the Microsoft support team that this script has to be executed in all web application mentioned in the hybrid search content source.

Comment: Thanks you for correcting my misunderstanding and sharing your solution.